# Yii Framework Extension

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm currently trying to use the YII Framework extensions. However, I have met up with some problems.

I have followed the step by step procedure in this website: https://github.com/drumaddict/skydrive-api-yii

However, when I call

```
Yii::import('protected.extensions.skydrive.SkyDriveAPI');
```

in the php.

It gives me
 `Uncaught exception 'CException' with message 'Alias "protected.extensions.skydrive.SkyDriveAPI" is invalid.`

I'm new to the Yii Framework and would need some help. May anyone give me some pointers.

Thanks,
Chan Yeoh

Comment: Hi, have you added your app to the MS website and replaced the API key?

Comment: did you put your files in folder skydrive inside extensions directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your extension is placed in `protected/extensions` just use:

```
Yii::import('ext.skydrive.SkyDriveAPI');
```

which is the same as:

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.skydrive.SkyDriveAPI');
```

Comment: Ok, I understand how this works. I was a beginneer in Yii, but after looking through the documentary. I start to get the hang of how things works. Thanks.